# iPhone and iPad application(same name-two project)...?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, universal

I'm creating an application that has to run on both iPad & iPhone/iPod. For that purpose I want to create two separate projects (one for iPhone, one for iPad) instead of one glitchy, universal application. I don't want to use each and every time constructions like `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`.So is it possible to have two projects with the same application name but just different target platforms?

If this is possible at all, how will it work when I upload them to iTunes store?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays not in code but in App Store rules: In iTunes Connect Apple does not let you create two applications with the same name.

So here's another proposal: Create two separate projects and combine them in a third wrapper project that is a universal application. Both of the projects use a different prefix for classes, so there are no name clashes. Then you only have very little to none common code with conditional paths for different devices (just the `main` function when using different app delegate classes).

Comment: Just drag the project from the Finder to the project outline.

Comment: Thanks but I need more information about this, can you provide me any tutorial or any kind of stuff which help me with the same thing which you suggest...!?!